# Binding services on Android in Dotnet MAUI

Tags: android, xamarin, maui

I am trying to bind a service on Android with Dotnet MAUI. I have the *exact* same code working as a Kotlin application, but OnServiceConnected is never called in Dotnet. BindService returns true. I am missing probably something obvious, but I can't find it.

The example code is given, including the AIDL stub, that is auto-generated into CS code by setting it to be an Android Interface Description.

```
package com.zebra.rfid.api3;

interface IRFIDDeviceInterface {
    void ledBlink();
}
```

```cs
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        var r = new RfidDeviceService(this);

        Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                r.Bind();
                while (true)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);

                    if (r.ServiceConnection.rfidDeviceInterface != null)
                    {
                        r.ServiceConnection.rfidDeviceInterface.LedBlink();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("nope");
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}

public class ServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
{
    public IRFIDDeviceInterface rfidDeviceInterface;

    public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
    {
        rfidDeviceInterface = IRFIDDeviceInterfaceStub.AsInterface(service);
    }

    public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
    {
        rfidDeviceInterface = null;
    }
}

public class RfidDeviceService
{
    public ServiceConnection ServiceConnection;
    private Context appContext;

    public RfidDeviceService(Context context)
    {
        ServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection();
        appContext = context;
    }

    public void Bind()
    {
        var serviceIntent = new Intent(nameof(IRFIDDeviceInterface));
        serviceIntent.SetClassName("com.zebra.rfid.rfidmanager", "com.zebra.rfid.rfidmanager.RFIDService");

        var result = appContext.BindService(serviceIntent, ServiceConnection, global::Android.Content.Bind.AutoCreate);
        Console.WriteLine($"Binded {result}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending a few more hours on this, the main problem is in creating the Intent.

It should be:

```cs
var rfidDeviceInterfaceType = typeof(IRFIDDeviceInterface);
var action = rfidDeviceInterfaceType.Namespace.ToLower() + "." + rfidDeviceInterfaceType.Name;
var serviceIntent = new Intent(action);
```

And that works.